# Convert blob image urls to Zip file by JSZip

Tags: zip, javascript-objects, jszip

My javascript code return list of images in form of blob urls like blob:http://localhost/93e9b867-ca7b-46cc-82fa-086b571b839e.

I want to make zip file of it through JSZip library.

```
 let zip = new JSZip();
 zip.file(what will be the code ?);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.